# Need help for sending email with attachment for windows platform(UWP react-native-windows)

Tags: windows, react-native, uwp, react-native-windows

I am using **react-native** for developing my UWP **windows** application(windows-10), and get stuck with **opening email application with attachment.**
React-native’s **Linking** is send mail **with text body and without any attachment.**
So, is there any functionality or **any library** which supports sending email with attachment for windows platform?

Comment: Why don't you do it with a hyperlink.